# image carousel + модальное окно javascript native

Tags: javascript, изображения, слайдер

Нужно все сделать на чистом Javascript.

У меня есть готовый слайдер с изображениями. Я нашел так же как открыть через кнопку модальное окно. Оба кода добавил в исходники.

1. Мне нужно чтобы по клику на изображение - оно появлялось в модальном
   окне увеличенным, соответственно закрыть его по крестику или пустому
   месту щелкая
2. При наведении курсора на боковую стрелку автоматическое перематывание останавливалось.

Моих знаний не хватает для понимания что искать чтобы разобраться, где и т.д.

Прошу помощи:
где почитать и что, чтобы разобраться + подсказки может какие

Благодарю)

```js
var slider = {
//массив с изображениями 
 slides: ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'],
 // начальный кадр (индекс из массива, нумерация с О) 
 frame:0, 
 set: function(image) { //установка нужного фона слайдеру 
  document.getElementById("scr").style.backgroundImage ="url("+image+")";
},

init: function () { // запуск слайдера с начальной картинкой 
 this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  },
left: function() { // влево 
 this.frame--; 
 if(this.frame < 0)this.frame = this.slides.length-1;
 this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
 },
right: function() { // вправо
 this.frame++;
 if(this.frame == this.slides.length)this.frame = 0;
  this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  } 
   };
   var btn = document.querySelector('.button'), // Главная кнопка
    modal = document.querySelector('.modal'), // Модальное окно
    closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBtn'); // Кнопка, закрывающая модальное окно

// Открытие модального окна
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = 'flex'; 
})
// Закрытие модального окна при клике на кнопку
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
 modal.style.display = "none";
})
// Закрытие модального окна при клике на серую область
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 if(e.target == modal) {
     modal.style.display = "none";
 }   
})
window.onload = function () { // запуск слайдера после загрузки документа EI'
 slider.init ();
 setInterval (function() {
 slider.right();
   },3000); // 3 сек после - переход на кадр справа 
    };
```

```css
#main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 940px;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#scr {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 1440px;
    height: 900px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 2px solid blaсk;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 470px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 70px;
    font: 12px Arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    left: 5px;
}

.right {
    right: 5px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(0,100, 250);
    margin: 50px;
}
.closeBtn{
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-size:20px;
  color: white;
}

.modal {
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    perspective: 500px;
    
}

.modal .modal-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    top: 15%;
    background: rgb(0,100, 250);
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    animation-name:modalopen;
    animation-duration:.8s;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {
    background: white;
}

@keyframes modalopen{
  from {
    opacity: 0; 
    top: 5%;
    transform: rotateX(15deg);
   }
  to {
    opacity: 1; 
    top: 15%; 
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>Cлaйдep</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,
  width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <button class="left" onclick="slider.left();"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="scr"></div>
        <button class="right" onclick="slider.right();">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
     <button class="button">Click me!</button>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
      <h3>I am modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus enim impedit maiores veritatis corrupti blanditiis molestias, hic illum architecto doloremque ad nostrum necessitatibus. Voluptatibus et aliquid est vitae dolor quia.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Hi! I am footer!</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <script src="native.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Можете воспользоваться уже готовыми решениями, есть куча плагинов для реализации, как с jquery так и на vanila JS, или вы хотите сами написать?

Comment: Вот плагин на чистом JS https://github.com/feimosi/baguetteBox.js